# How to customize AddThis Photo Sharing Tool

Tags: javascript, customization, addthis

I am using [AddThis' Photo Sharing Tool](http://www.addthis.com/labs/photo-sharing) and I like it but I would like to customize it a bit and not sure how to do that.

AddThis says to put this code into your site:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var addthis_config = {    
    services_overlay:'facebook,twitter,email,more'
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
  src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js"></script>
```

You can add services by adding their name. Then you add `class="addthis_shareable"` to the image itself and you are set to go. However I would like to customize AddThis a bit more and not sure how to do this.

I would like to:

1. Reduce the size of the icons from 32x32 to 16x16.
2. Change how quickly the items show when the image is hovered over.
3. If possible show the icons for half a second before fading out to indicate they are there to the user.

Any help with the above would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a [JSFiddle of the Code](http://jsfiddle.net/Lynda333/3dx9N/1/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have more control over the buttons, you need to create them and configure using attributes which would drive the look and feel. You would add the buttons like so

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style">
  <a class="addthis_button_facebook" addthis:ui_hover_delay="200" addthis:ui_delay="500"></></a>
  <a class="addthis_button_twitter" addthis:ui_hover_delay="200" addthis:ui_delay="500"></a>
  <a class="addthis_button_email" addthis:ui_hover_delay="200" addthis:ui_delay="500"></a>
</div>
```

The print menu might be appearing because of adding the "more" in the service configuration. If removing that doesn't work, try setting the "services_exclude" in the config object to "print"

Comment: The print icon showing was a conflict with this script: `var addthis_config = {"data_track_clickback":true};` once removed the icon went away.

Comment: ui_hover_delay is no longer listed as an [addthis_config Variable](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/1337994-the-addthis_config-variable).